# Board-to-Board (B2B) connector for Raspberry Pi

Tags: connection

I have a BLE module that connects to its original MCU board with a 30 pin CN2 type board-to-board (B2B) connector.

I want to use this BLE module in Raspberry Pi. I've some BLE related code that runs on Raspberry Pi. Now I want to make sure that this code works with this new BLE module (that has B2B connector).

I understand that Raspberry Pi doesn't have this type of B2B connector. Is there any B2B to USB converter? Or any other way I can connect this BLE module with Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Can you include a picture of the connector you're interested in? "B2B" is a generic description of what a connector is used for; it's not a specific type of connector, so we can't determine what you're actually asking here. (And "CN2" just means it's the second connector on the board.)